# What part of speech is 'two o'clock' in this sentence?

Tags: parsing, adverbs

I thought adverbs didn't modify nouns but then what's going on in these sentences:

> It is nearly two o'clock
>
> We were there for nearly an hour
>
> The town is nearly forty miles from here

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE. This question seems to have several problems, you may need to review the site [tour](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what questions fit best here. First, the question does not indicate any own research effort. Try answering the question yourself and post what specific problems you're facing when answering. We don't do someone else's homeworks either. Also, it seems to be English-specific, so another site may be a better fit.

Comment: You're wrong, "o'clock" is not a noun. Why not [look it up in a dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/o%27clock)? And why not learn that adverbs [_can_ modify nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb)?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm sorry if the question is inappropriate, I will refrain from asking similar ones in future, but it's not homework- I am just trying to improve my understanding of grammar and have tied myself in knots. It's difficult for me to be more specific than to say that I am just unsure what's going on in these sentences. My best guess would be that they are adverbial phrases, is that on the right lines?

Comment: @YellowSky, why not read the Wikipedia reference you cite?  And why not learn it says that in the only cases that adverbs modify nouns they follow the nouns they modify?

Comment: I think the question is fine -- it cites some received wisdom ("adverbs don't modify nouns"), presents counterexamples, and asks how this can be reconciled. The answer, I'd say, is that such examples show that adverbs can indeed modify nouns, or rather noun phrases.

Comment: @GregLee - Why not read the examples in that article? **Even** camels need to drink. I bought **only** the fruit. She drove us **almost** to the station. However strange it may seem to you, but in these sentences adverbs _precede_ the nouns they modify, they don't follow them.

Comment: @YellowSky, Read more carefully.  None of those examples is a case of an adjective modifying a noun.  Can you tell the difference between a noun and a noun phrase?

Comment: @GregLee - Adjectives? We speak about adverbs here, not adjectives. _Camels_, _the fruit_, _to the station_ are noun phrases, a "bare" noun is a particular case of a noun phrase.

Comment: @YellowSky, It's probably true that adverbs can precede the noun phrases they modify.  Adverbs do not modify following nouns, and the Wikipedia article you referred to does not say they do.  Noun phrases are not the same as nouns.  Just because an adverb modifies a following noun phrase, this does not mean that it modifies the noun inside that noun phrase, even in the case where the noun phrase contains nothing besides a single noun.  Noun phrases are not the same as nouns.  Noun phrases are not the same as nouns.

Comment: @YellowSky Whilst adverbs may be able to modify nouns in many languages and exceptionally postmodify them in English too, that page is a pile of pants that can't tell a noun from a preposition from an adverb. If one could vote to close wikipedia pages, that would be high up on my list for closure.

Comment: @YellowSky Lastly looking up parts of speech in a dictionary is the most ridiculous advice you could ever give on a site like this. They're about 100 years out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think that "two o'clock" is a noun phrase, and in "nearly two o'clock" the "nearly" is an adverb modifying the determiner (Det) "two" within that noun phrase.  The constituent structure is:

> [NP [Det [Adv nearly] [Det two] ] o'clock ]

This analysis is a little tricky for your example "nearly an hour", since "nearly an" cannot stand alone, and you have to consider that "an" is a reduced form of "one".  But at least that makes sense of the construction, because "nearly an hour" does mean that the quantity of hours was almost one, and the full form "nearly one hour" is an acceptable paraphrase.

Comment: It's very counterintuitive (to me anyway) to make *two* a determiner and *o'clock* a noun. I'd say that *two* is a noun in this sentence and *o'clock* is modifying it.

Comment: @TKR, I classify "two o'clock" as a noun phrase because it can occur in the positions other noun phrases occur in: subject, direct object, object of preposition.  The usual structure of a noun phrase is Det plus noun, and that's why I give "two o'clock" this structure.  If you think that "two o'clock" is a modified noun, you should be thinking about whether it occurs in the positions that other modified nouns occur in.  A green two o'clock just ran past my window.

Comment: I agree that *two o'clock* is an NP, but I'd consider *two* the head. Not all NPs have a determiner, and *two* is semantically primary here, unlike *o'clock*. What would you say about *It's nearly two*? Is *two* just a determiner by itself? That doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @TKR, In "It's nearly two", "nearly two" is a NP with unspecified head, understood to mean "o'clock", and Det "nearly two". And "two" is, as you suggest, a Det, modified by "nearly".

Comment: Well, noun ellipsis is pretty restricted in English, but in any case *o'clock* is pretty clearly not a noun: *the o'clock, *an o'clock, etc. I don't see the problem with making the numeral the head: "It's two" strikes me as completely equivalent to "It's February", where "February" is clearly a bare-noun NP.

Comment: @TKR, "It's two" means "It's two o'clock" (as one possibility), but "It's February" does not mean *"It's February o'clock" (which is not even grammatical).  And you think they are "completely equivalent"?  Do you really think "two" is a proper noun like "February"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29736/discussion-between-tkr-and-greg-lee).

Comment: Wouldn't _o'clock_ be a prepositional phrase?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut, it could very well be a prepositional phrase.  However, I don't see how that helps us understand its grammar in current English.

Comment: So is 'nearly' modifying the noun phrase?

Comment: As a whole, I mean? Or is it modifying an element of the noun phrase?

Comment: @Beth6147 That's what the disagreement is about -- I would say it's modifying the entire NP, Greg Lee thinks it's modifying only a determiner within that NP.

Comment: @Beth6147, yes, as TKR says, I gave in my answer the opinion that "nearly" modifies "two".

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut, if "o'clock" is a prepositional phrase modifying "hours", then that explains why "o'clock" can be singular, even though the quantifier "two" ordinarily requires a plural.

Comment: Thank you both, I'm afraid your discussion is beyond me but I really appreciate the input!

Comment: "O'clock" might as well just be a PP as it is a contraction of "of the clock".

Comment: Yes, it's [nearly two], [nearly one], [nearly forty] etc